# How to limit use of other apps on android

Tags: java, android

We are building an app for Android that has parental locks. I have been reading about broadcast receivers, but am struggling to find specifics on what we are trying to do.

This is how the app works:

1. There is an icon for our app on the lock screen (we have done this already)
2. A parent logs in and will see a list of EVERY app on the device. If we could show it's app icon great - if not we can settle for the name of the app only.
3. The parent then sets which apps can be used on the device and which cannot
4. If a child closes our app - if they load another restricted app, it will automatically be "killed"

What I need help figuring out:

1. How can i get a list of apps on the device?
2. How can i restrict usage of apps on the device?

There are other apps that are doing this - but I'm struggling to find the right documentation.

Comment: You'll need platform keys or root to make this happen. There are some "hacky" work-arounds, but nothing that's reliable. Your best bet is to create a custom launcher with restrictions and call it "child mode." -- or use the JB multi-user features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your first problem:

to get the list of installed apps

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

and for getting the icon with name

```
String label = (String)pm.getApplicationLabel(app);
Drawable icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(app);
```

and about your second problem, I think what 323go said is right.